# Trying to get an accurate float point. python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda

When I try getting an error for a general trapezoidal approximation
(the error equation to be used is: `(1/3)*(I2-I1)`
I get `-0.0`. I would like for this to be floating but it will not show any numbers after the decimal after it has been shown. How do I fix this?
This is the code:

```
error = float((1/3)*(dx*(y[3] +y[2]) - dx* (y[1] + y[0]*0.5)))
print error
```

where y is an array of values

```
[  1.       0.8001   0.6016   0.4081   0.2256   0.0625  -0.0704  -0.1599
  -0.1904  -0.1439   0.       0.2641   0.6736   1.2561   2.0416   3.0625
   4.3536   5.9521   7.8976  10.2321  13.    ]
```

The equation of *y* is `x**4 - 2*x + 1`
And the *x* bound are `0. -> 2.`

Comment: The error is -0.0, error (i.e error = float....) is merely the name of my variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because 1/3 in your equation ends up being an integer operation and ends up casting the remainder of the calculation to integer math.

Comment: Yeah - in Python 2.7, `1/3 = 0`. Try using `1./3`.

Comment: Note, that you can start your imports with  `from __future__ import division`. After that the `/` operator will behave the same as in python3: `1/3` evaluates to `0.33333`